# how to assign a user in a particular group in the registration process itself in django

Tags: django, assign, django-users, django-managers, usergroups

I have created a custom user creation form in which I included a choice field 'Company' & 'Truck' so that user can be identified according to the field. Here is my registration page[image] I also created two groups Truck & Company via admin page. I want to assign a specific user in the registration process to the particular group so that, I later want to give the permissions to a particular user on their group basis. I tried by creating a def as assign_group in EmailUserManager. But not working as I wanted. Please help me how can I assign the users to the particular groups.

models.py:

```
 """User models."""
import django
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin, Group)
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EmailUserManager(BaseUserManager):

"""Custom manager for EmailUser."""

def _create_user(self, email, password,
                 is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save an EmailUser with the given email and password.

    :param str email: user email
    :param str password: user password
    :param bool is_staff: whether user staff or not
    :param bool is_superuser: whether user admin or not
    :return custom_user.models.EmailUser user: user
    :raise ValueError: email is not set

    """
    now = timezone.now()
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    is_active = extra_fields.pop("is_active", True)
    user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=is_active,
                      is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                      date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save an EmailUser with the given email and password.

    :param str email: user email
    :param str password: user password
    :return custom_user.models.EmailUser user: regular user

    """
    is_staff = extra_fields.pop("is_staff", False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, is_staff, False,
                             **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save an EmailUser with the given email and password.

    :param str email: user email
    :param str password: user password
    :return custom_user.models.EmailUser user: admin user

    """
    return self._create_user(email, password, True, True,
                             **extra_fields)


class EmailUser(AbstractEmailUser):

"""
Concrete class of AbstractEmailUser.

Use this if you don't need to extend EmailUser.

"""
CHOICES = (('Truck', 'Truck'),('Company', 'Company'),)
Label = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=20)

def assign_group(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=is_staff, is_active=is_active,
                      is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                      date_joined=now, Label=label, **extra_fields)
    if user.Label == 'Truck':
        g1 = Group.objects.get(name=Truck)
        g1.user_set.add(TRUCK_USER)
        user_group.save()
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    elif user.Label == 'Company':
        g2 = Group.objects.get(name=Company)
        g2.user_set.add(COMPANY_USER)
        user_group.save()
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
class Meta(AbstractEmailUser.Meta):
    swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

forms.py:

```
 class EmailUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

"""A form for creating new users.

Includes all the required fields, plus a repeated password.

"""

error_messages = {
    'duplicate_email': _("A user with that email already exists."),
    'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
}

password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

CHOICES= (('Truck', 'Truck'),('Company', 'Company'),)
Label = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label='Label', widget=forms.RadioSelect())

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'Label',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.keyOrder = ['email', 'password1', 'password2', 'Label']

def clean_email(self):
    """Clean form email.

    :return str email: cleaned email
    :raise forms.ValidationError: Email is duplicated

    """
    # Since EmailUser.email is unique, this check is redundant,
    # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        get_user_model()._default_manager.get(email=email)
    except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
        return email
    raise forms.ValidationError(
        self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],
        code='duplicate_email',
    )

def clean_password2(self):
    """Check that the two password entries match.

    :return str password2: cleaned password2
    :raise forms.ValidationError: password2 != password1

    """
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    """Save user.

    Save the provided password in hashed format.

    :return custom_user.models.EmailUser: user

    """
    user = super(EmailUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer before question edit:

Find the group object by Label and add user object to that group.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
g = Group.objects.get(name=LABEL_NAME) 
g.user_set.add(YOUR_USER)
```

Update 1:

Groups are like categories. You just put users in some categories. When we talk about group permissions, we usually handle them via utility functions such as:

```
def is_truck(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='truck').exists()

def is_company(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='company').exists()
```

or you can make properties on user objects.

Comment: should i create some permissions in the emailusermanager for assigning and managing the groups? If so, what should i do?

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer. So, how can I do putting some user into a group that I have created directly after the user registration process?

Comment: I am new to django. Even after adding g = Group.objects.get(name=LABEL_NAME) 
g.user_set.add(YOUR_USER) in my code, i couldn't able to assign a registered user to a spcific group. How can i resolve that?

Comment: Yes, you can directly add user in any group during registration. As to the other question, you can cross check against some user after adding them to any group. For instance, go to `./manage.py shell` and create one user, say `u`. Now, add that user `u` to any group, say `company`. Now, when you do `u.groups.filter(name='company').exists()` it should return `True`.

Comment: I don't want to add a user to group manually. I couldn't to able to solve how to assign user automatically to a group. For this, what exactly i should do? Actually i created my registration page such that i can get the info about the user_type. But i don't how to use this data and assign that user to the specific group automatically. Initially i thought of creating assign_group in my customuser manager and later i make it into customuser. But its not working. May be some wrong in the code. Can you help me solving this.

Comment: I explained you the manual version so that you can cross check! Then replicate the procedure in the `save()` method to make things work programmatically.